# Angular 6 HTML response from HttpClient POST request

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to make a third party authorisation. When I hit a POST request to server, it sends HTML as response.

**Header**

```
private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept': 'text/html',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}),
    responseType: 'text',
};
```

**API Call**

```
return this.http.post(this.authUrl, this.httpOptions)
    .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

I am getting a SyntaxError:

> Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse

Comment: you are missing http body argument

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept': 'text/html',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }),
    responseType: 'text'
};
```

Your HTTP options had an extra comma after `responseType:'Text'`

```
return this.http.post(this.authUrl,null, this.httpOptions)
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

Also, HTTP POST for [HttpClientModule](https://angular.io/guide/http) takes in payload as second argument within the POST call.

Comment: "Your http options had an extra comma after responseType:'Text'". It is still valid code.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best way to put your response type is when you are calling the http post this will stopped the HttpClient from trying to parse the empty response as a JSON object.

```
 this.http.put(
 url,
 data,
 {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json'),
    responseType: 'text' 
 }
 ).subscribe(  ....   );
```

with post

```
return this.http.post(url, params, {headers : headers, withCredentials : true,responseType: 'text'});
```